# Angular4 how to upload photo to S3 AWS

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have problem with uploading photos to my AWS S3.

My code in angular 4 looks like this:

```
upload(input) {
    let AWSService = window.AWS;

    let file = input.target.files[0];
    AWSService.config.update({
        region: "us-east-1",
        credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: "us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        })
    });

    let bucket = new AWSService.S3({
        params: {
            Bucket: "NAME"
        }
    });
    let params = {
        Key: file.name,
        Body: file
    };
    bucket.upload(params, (res) => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}

require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk');
```

Unfortunately, I am always receiving:

> 403 forbidden error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you place your bucket key and how to you authenticate it

Comment: There are lot of code that is missing to make it valid. Complete working example is covered by AWS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden is coming from AWS S3. No problem with angular.

AWS documentation has a complete example of maintaining photo album with S3.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS cors configuration

Add

`<AllowHeader>` * `<AllowHeader>`